# finding fourier coefficients for $ f(x)= \sin^k (x) , k \in \mathbb{N} $

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, trigonometric-series

I want to find the fourier coefficients  for $ f(x)= 
\sin^k (x) , k \in \mathbb{N} $.

Calculating $$ \tilde{f}(n)= \frac{1}{2 \pi } \int_{0}^{ 2 \pi} \sin^k(x) e^{-inx} dx$$

If I rewrite $\sin$ in terms of complex exponentials

$$ \tilde{f} (n) = \frac{1}{2 \pi } \int_{0}^{ 2 \pi} \left(\frac{e^{ix} -e^{-ix}}{2i} \right)^k e^{-inx} dx  $$

How to proceed from here?

Edit for expanding with binomial theorem:

$$sin^k(x) = \frac{1}{(2i)^k} ( e^{ix}-e^{-ix})^k $$
$ = \frac{1}{(2i)^k} \sum_{j=0}^k $  $ k \choose{j} $ $(e^{ix})^{k-j}(-e^{-ix})^j) $

$= \frac{1}{(2i)^k} \sum_{j=0}^k $  $ k \choose{j} $ $e^{ixk-j}(-e^{-ixj})$

so it gets to :

$ \tilde{f} (n) = \frac{1}{2 \pi } \int_{0}^{ 2 \pi} \frac{1}{(2i)^k} \sum_{j=0}^k $  $ k \choose{j} $ $e^{ixk-j}(-e^{-ixj}) e^{-inx} dx  $

is this even right so far or have I made a mistake?
how can I calculate an integral like this though..o.o

Comment: I think you're better off computing the integral.  It's not bad when you use Euler's identity to rewrite $ \sin(x) $ as a sum of exponential functions.  Then you will use binomial expansion to raise to the $k$.

Comment: Expand with the binomial theorem.